# How can I improve the startup time of my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, performance, startup

Why iPhone app's splash screen takes more time for loading?

Can we set the time for few second only? it takes almost one minute at the moment.

Answer (score 7):

Well the splash screen is shown as long as your app is starting, meaning not returning from the `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` method.

If you are doing a lot of thing in this method then you should spilt up that code to do then at an other point in the start up of your app.

You should keep the startup time of your app as short as possible, start maintance code in separate thread, try lazy loading for every thing else.

Comment: i am writing on - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{  self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

Comment: If that's all in your startup method then you must have a massive initial xib file!

Comment: @thanks for answering me @rckoenes. i am new in iphone please give me any idea about lazzy loading please

Comment: I think @rckoenes meant "lazy loading". It simply means to run the slow part in a separate task or thread.

Comment: Lazy loading means, that you only load a view, class, object, ect when you really need it. It's mostly used when working with tableviews and image that are retrieved from the internet. You will only fetch the image when your are about to display the cell. You can do the retrieving in a separate thread.

Comment: @pinku: you may check out this link for lazy loading http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: Thanks but its dificult for me sir

Comment: "Try lazy loading", how about putting them into becomeActive delegate method?

Answer (score 2):

The splash screen stays up until your app finishes initialising. Either speed up your initialisation code, or move the slow bits into a background task.

Answer (score 2):

Are you timing this while in XCode? If you are then don't - XCode has to attach debuggers and all sorts of things before the app starts up.

To get a real time, build a release version and put it on a device. Then disconnect the device and start your app. that should give you a real-world indication of how long it will take.

Comment: how to use lazzy image loading for loading an image. plz help us

Comment: I'm sure if you ask a question on stackoverflow showing your current image loading code someone will be glad to help you . . .